# Workflow Service not available during State Transition

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, state-machine

We've built Workflow Service that operates as State Machine.

One of the possible WCF calls into Workflow Service, causes Workflow to return to the same State it was before (starting State and ending State is the same as no condition has been met to move to new state).

What we've noticed is that during state transition, any other request sent to Workflow Service ends up with communication error - no endpoint listening on that port. Once the Workflow ends state transition, same request to Workflow Service can be done again.

What it seems to us is that during state transition, all listening endpoints on Workflow Service are severed.

How to deal with this? Clearly, we can capture the exception on client side, and do a retry, but is there a better, built in option?

We've looked into Buffered Receive option, but it seems that one is making a queue, meaning that it would even accept messages for the State that is not even reached yet.